# What is the correct way of installing BOINC software?

Tags: installation, boinc

I've been trying to install the Boinc software (http://boinc.berkeley.edu/), I could do it in Ubuntu 12.04 but it never worked as well as in Windows (couldn't get it on the systray icons, to be a startup application etc.), but in Ubuntu 12.10 I can't even install it to get the interface, there's a lot of versions and ways to install it.

Anyone knows the correct way for installing and using Boinc in Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

### Graphical Installation

You need to install the client software, which will act as a daemon and boinc client will be automatically started at boot time.

Command to install boinc-client

```
sudo apt-get install boinc-client
```

You need the boinc manager to have a graphical interface to monitor and control boinc client.

Command to install boinc-manager

```
sudo apt-get install boinc-manager
```

Both the above commands can be combined and run together as

```
sudo apt-get install boinc-client boinc-manager
```

To open Boinc Manager. Use dash(Super Key) and search for "boinc"

### Non-Graphical Installation

If you are not looking for a graphical interface you just need to install boinc-client

```
sudo apt-get install boinc-client
```

### Via Ubuntu Software Center

You can also use Ubuntu Software Center to install Boinc. Search for "boinc-client" in Ubuntu Software Center.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Thanks for your answear! The problem is that the version isn't the last one, and I can't get the way of updating it.

The other problem is I can't it to become a startupapplication.

Comment: In Quantal repositories 7.0.27 is the latest version. Check the version installed in your machine using `apt-cache policy bonic-manager`

Answer (score 2):

Just install it using the package manager. Package names: `boinc` and [`boinc-manager`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/boinc-manager). E.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install boinc-manager
```

And it should be available in the regular application menu.